# How to generate .hhp file from windows command prompt?

Tags: html, windows, command-prompt, chm

My goal is to achieve an automated process which converts HTML files into the CHM file format.
I am able to generate chm file using hhp from command line.

> hhc filename.hhp

But hhp file was generated using HTML helper tool. How I can create hhp file using the command line? 
Or how to created a CHM file if you have HTML files only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the hhp by hand or generate using a different programming language. The .hhp is just html tool's project, containing the settings and filelist for conversion

The best solution is to integrate the hhp generation with your html generation if you do so.

Comment: yes, I have run the python script to generate, hhp. It is working fine.